# Create a sub-list according to criteria and Perform operations

Tags: java, java-8

I have sorted `List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>` and I want to create a subList for all the Pairs which having a key less than one arbitrary value k.

> I want to create a subList that follows above condition and sort it.

I did something like this -

```
//to get the max index of the List
public static int getIndex(List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> list,int key)
{
   int count=0;
   for(Pair<Integer,Integer> p: list)
   {
       if(p.getKey()>key)
         break;                 
    count++;
     }
   return count;
}
```

### Now, Sorting subList as per this criteria

```
 int count = getIndex(current.getValue(),list);
 Collections.sort(list.subList(0, count),Comparator.<Pair<Integer,Integer>>comparingInt(Pair::getValue));
```

#### Is there any elegent way to do achieve this ? I mean java 8 way.

Stream API came into my mind. But after performing operations it doesn't manipulate the underlined collection.

Comment: Aside from that `<Pair<Integer,Integer>>` in the comparator declaration your sort() line doesn't look that inelegant. However, I'm not sure I get the purpose of `count`: do you really want to only sort the pairs before the first one whose key is greater than `current.getValue()`? Since you'd then sort part of the list not by key but by value wouldn't that interfere with any further code?

Comment: Btw, instead of a linear search you could use binary search if the list is sorted by key. For this you could use `Collections.binarySearch()` with a custom comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following.

```java
  List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> subList = 
                 list.stream()
                     .filter(p->p.getKey() <  key)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This works regardless of the ordering of the pairs in the list. It constructs the new list as each `pair` passes thru the filter.

Comment: The above also presumes that the comparison is using numbers (hence the < sign).  I did not know how you implemented the Comparable interface but that could be applied too.  If you are comparing `Pairs`, you would not specify a `key` directly but a special instance of `Pair` with the desired `key` as the argument of the `compareTo`